# Connected to router but without internet

Tags: linux-networking, eth0, linuxmint

My Linux Mint 17 box is connected to a router via eth0, of which is connected to the internet.  However, my box cannot access websites or ping `google.com` etc.

I am sure the problem is with the DNS lookup since it is possible to ping outside IP addresses, just not their host names.

What is missing in my configuration?

**/etc/network/interfaces**

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.200
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
```

**ifconfig**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 80:ee:73:36:eb:e4
          inet addr:192.168.0.200  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::82ee:73ff:fe36:ebe4/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2388 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2583 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:313912 (313.9 KB)  TX bytes:1932766 (1.9 MB)
          Interrupt:46

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:927 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:927 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:73985 (73.9 KB)  TX bytes:73985 (73.9 KB)
```

Comment: What is in /etc/resolv.conf?

Comment: `nameserver 8.8.8.8`

Comment: what is the out put of lookup / dig  command ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding nameserver to your interfaces file under eth0:

```
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```